# Graficas de pastel

Tags: php, javascript, json, chart.js

¿Cómo puedo hacer un piechart con datos que vienen desde un web service?.

Los datos que arroja el web service vienen en formato json; este es un ejemplo de la salida de mi web service, el cual se llama `ws_lugares.php`:

```
{
"procede": "1",
"status": "1",
"statusText": "Correct",
 "Lugares": [
        {
"México": "3",
"Ecuador": "2",
"Tijuana": "5"
  }
  ]
}
```

***** E ESTADO UTILIZANDO este codigo  el url: que es donde esta localizado mi web service ******

```
    <script>
        $.ajax({
        url: '../ws_lugares.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $(this).serialize()

    })
    .done(function (respuesta) {
        console.log(respuesta);
        if (!respuesta.error) { //Aqui se les da el valor de el ws a variables para despues llamarlas en el value de la grafica

 } else {
            $('.error').slideDown('slow');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('.error').slideUp('slow');
            }, 3500);

        }
    })
    .fail(function (resp) {
        console.log(resp.responseText);
    })
    .always(function () {
        console.log("complete");
    });

        var pieChartCanvas = $('#pieChart').get(0).getContext('2d')
          var pieChart       = new Chart(pieChartCanvas)
          var PieData        = [
            {
              value    : //Aqui se llama la 1er var,
              color    : '#f56954',
              highlight: '#f56954',
              label    : 'Chrome'
            },
            {
              value    : //aqui se llama la 2da ,
              color    : '#00a65a',
              highlight: '#00a65a',
              label    : 'IE'
            },
            {
              value    : /aqui se llama la tercer,
              color    : '#f39c12',
              highlight: '#f39c12',
              label    : 'FireFox'
            }
          ]
          var pieOptions     = {
            //Boolean - Whether we should show a stroke on each segment
            segmentShowStroke    : true,
            //String - The colour of each segment stroke
            segmentStrokeColor   : '#fff',
            //Number - The width of each segment stroke
            segmentStrokeWidth   : 2,
            //Number - The percentage of the chart that we cut out of the middle
            percentageInnerCutout: 50, // This is 0 for Pie charts
            //Number - Amount of animation steps
            animationSteps       : 100,
            //String - Animation easing effect
            animationEasing      : 'easeOutBounce',
            //Boolean - Whether we animate the rotation of the Doughnut
            animateRotate        : true,
            //Boolean - Whether we animate scaling the Doughnut from the centre
            animateScale         : false,
            //Boolean - whether to make the chart responsive to window resizing
            responsive           : true,
            // Boolean - whether to maintain the starting aspect ratio or not when responsive, if set to false, will take up entire container
            maintainAspectRatio  : true,
            //String - A legend template
            legendTemplate       : '<ul class="<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style="background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>'
          }

        </script>
```

***esto es lo que e intentado claro que tengo el #piechart pero no lo coloque aqui ya que el problema que tengo es que no se como acomodar los valores de el ws para plasmarlos en la grafica****

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el de Google:

```js
google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        
        //Aquí colocarias el ajax
        const dataWebServices = {
          "procede": "1",
          "status": "1",
          "statusText": "Correct",
          "Lugares": [
              {
                "México": "3",
                "Ecuador": "2",
                "Tijuana": "5",
                "Venezuela": "2"
              }
            ]
        };
        
        var lugares = dataWebServices.Lugares[0];
        var arrayLugares = [];
        arrayLugares.push(['Lugares', 'Paises/Estados']);
        Object.keys(lugares).forEach(function(lugar) {
         let item = [lugar, parseFloat(lugares[lugar])];
         arrayLugares.push(item)
        });
                          
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayLugares);

        var options = {
          title: 'Lugares',
          pieHole: 0.4,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
<div id="donutchart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

Como veras la magia está en la función **drawChart()** el cual puedes colocar tu ajax donde llamas a tu webservices, de todas maneras coloque el resultado de tu json en una variable para emular, luego obtuve el valor que me interesa el cual es **dataWebServices.Lugares[0]** el cual contiene los **países/regiones**, luego cree un array **arrayLugares** donde su primer valor tiene que ser un etiqueta que haga referencia a los valores que vayas a introducir, puedes colocar allí cualquier cosa pero debe ser **string**, luego en el **forEach** voy recorriendo cada región para luego insertarlo en el array **arrayLugares** para ir formando la data que necesita el gráfico.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Para más info puedes ir [aquí](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#fullhtml).